# Intellij Scala not recognizing operators

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) with Scala, developing using IntelliJ IDEA Community 13. I've got Play running from a terminal; that's all working. However, IntelliJ isn't recognizing some of the operators used on strings.

Here's my code:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Redirect(routes.Application.tasks)
  }

  def tasks = TODO

  def newTask = TODO

  def deleteTask(id: Long) = TODO

  def sayHello = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    (request.body \ "name").asOpt[String].map { name =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(
        Map("status" -> "OK", "message" -> ("Hello " + name)) // this line
      ))
    }.getOrElse {
      BadRequest("Missing parameter [name]")
    }
  }

}
```

It compiles and runs fine in Play. However, IntelliJ marks the `+` and `->` operators as invalid, giving me a **"Cannot resolve symbol `+`"** when I hover.

I know this is more of an inconvenience than anything else, but it's really bothering me. **What do I have to import or configure in order to get IntelliJ to recognize those operators?**

Comment: Those don't come from Play, they're stock Scala. Most likely you haven't configured the Scala standard library JARs as a dependency for your project. I recommend using SBT and the gen-idea plug-in to generate a complete IDEA project with all its dependencies properly reflecting those in your build.sbt or build.scala file(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently, JetBrains have taken a "forever in beta" approach with Scala plugin, so be prepared to see bugs frequently. I report them on a daily basis, and I gotta admit, that they do solve the issues I post. Basically what I wanna say is whenever you come across any issue with Scala plugin just post it [on their issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL).

Answer (score 0):

Once you confirm you have the latest versions of the Scala and Play plugins installed and configured, create a new Play application with IntelliJ as described [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Play+Framework+2.0).

@Randall's approach to the problem from the other side, having Play generate an IntelliJ project, should work, but I personally have found issues with that because of a lagging behind due to changes made by JetBrains to IntelliJ. It might still work for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Randall gave the answer in his comment, you probabally haven't set up your project correctly, or have forgotten to do `sbt gen-idea` (and restart/reload Intellij) after adding dependencies.  Additionally I've noticed weird Intellij nonrecognition errors often go away after updates to the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem when I was using `mkString` method in scala. And the intellij was throwing compiler alert as

> cannot recognise symbol mkString

But when I applied `toString` method before using the `mkString` method. The alert was gone and the code compiled successfully